# how to disable the "laxcomma" check?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I'm using SublimeLintern package, but I'm experiencing some issues. I would like to toggle that "laxcomma" warning that appears each time I save my files: I do prefer putting my commas at the beginning of each row

```
{
  "item1": val1
  ,"item2": val2
  ,"item3": val3
}
```

Hence, I tried to look for some piece of documentation that explained how to enable or disable each check. I bumped into [this](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/blob/master/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings) that should explain what I need.
So, my `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` is now like this:

```
{
    "jshint_options": {
        "laxcomma": false
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. I still see that bothering warning! What's wrong with my settings?

Comment: Have you looked at lines 284 and 285 of `/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/libs/jshint/jshint.js`?  You might want to set `laxbreak` and `laxcomma` to `false`.

Comment: Yep! I've tried both, but nothing happens

Comment: May you try this out on your SBT2 `sublimelinter.sublime-settings` file and tell me if it works properly? In case it works: may you paste a gist here? Thanks

Comment: Is this still relevant? I do get warning for comma at the beginning of each line rather than end! But code seems to work fine on pretty much all browsers!

Answer (score 4):

Bizarre.  For me, the issue was that I had a `.jshintrc` file in the local directory of my project.  Despite the fact that `laxcomma` wasn't being overridden *there EITHER*, apparently it just completely overrides your jshint_options (or maybe it does a top-level extend and doesn't recursively merge the config objects...)

The solution was to add (to the local `.jshintrc` file):

`"laxcomma": true`

Comment: And in a simple command you can do 
bash$:> `echo '"laxcomma": true' >> ~/.jshintrc`

Comment: doesn't work for me. maybe i need to restart webstorm?

Comment: @chovy yeah maybe quit out of it completely and open it again-- my solution isn't necessarily a surefire fix for your situation, since it does seem that this stuff is a bit editor-dependent

Comment: My project had more than one version of this file. :)

Answer (score 1):

The word "lax" means not strict or severe; if you want to put your commas at the beginning of each line, try setting "laxcomma" to **true**:

```
{
    "jshint_options": {
        "laxcomma": true
    }
}
```

Comment: this is part of my .sublime-project content `"jshint_options": { "laxcomma": true }` I tried with both `true` and `false` but nothing happens, this is the message I get after saving my file: 'comma warnings can be turned off with 'laxcomma'; bad line breaking before ','
I don't know the cause of that _bad line breaking_ actually.

Comment: Correct for 'The word "lax" means not strict or severe'